# is it possible to track the progress of a function like melt in package reshape?

Tags: r, progress, reshape, melt

I am aware that I can create a progress bar for a self-created loop or something like that. However, is it possible to somehow keep a track of the progress for a function like `melt()` from the `reshape` package. Or the only way to track progress is either to extrapolate the time needed for this function to work on smaller data-set?

Comment: your question is unclear i am afraid. is it possible to give a practical example?

Comment: I'm almost sure there is no easy way to do so, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to get a progress bar for a function that doesn't already have one. If you were really motivated, you could dig into the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/reshape) for reshape2 and add the functionality (or the source for the more modern equivalent, `tidyr`). If you have a logical way of breaking down your dataset, you could use `purr::map` and write a custom function that reports on its own progress. If you post an example of your data I'd be happy to show you how that could work.

As an aside, it can be difficult to "extrapolate the time needed for this function to work on smaller data-set." The code below reshapes datasets with an n of 1000, 10000, 100000, and 1000000 and then times how long they take to run. The amount of time per row of data varies wildly. On my computer, the time-per-row was 24 times greater for the dataset with 1000 rows compared to the dataset with 1000000 rows. That makes it challenging to predict how long the `melt` function will take.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

# Create dummy data with different numbers of rows
dummy_1k <-
  tibble(group = 1:1000,
         test1 = rnorm(1000),
         test2 = runif(1000))
dummy_10k <-
  tibble(
    group = 1:10000,
    test1 = rnorm(10000),
    test2 = runif(10000)
  )
dummy_100k <-
  tibble(
    group = 1:100000,
    test1 = rnorm(100000),
    test2 = runif(100000)
  )
dummy_1000k <-
  tibble(
    group = 1:1000000,
    test1 = rnorm(1000000),
    test2 = runif(1000000)
  )

# Define a convenience function to melt our dummy data
molten_dummy <- function(dum_df) {
  reshape2::melt(dum_df, id = "group")
}

# Measure how long it takes to melt a row of data based
# on the number of rows in the tibble
microbenchmark(
  molten_dummy(dummy_1k),
  molten_dummy(dummy_10k),
  molten_dummy(dummy_100k),
  molten_dummy(dummy_1000k),
  times = 1000L, unit = "ms"
) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  left_join(tribble(
  ~expr, ~count,
  "molten_dummy(dummy_1k)", 1000,
  "molten_dummy(dummy_10k)", 10000,
  "molten_dummy(dummy_100k)", 100000,
  "molten_dummy(dummy_1000k)", 1000000
)) %>%
  mutate(count = as.integer(count), time_per_row = time / count) %>%
  group_by(count) %>%
  summarise(time_per_row = mean(time_per_row)) %>%
  arrange(count)
```